# Error Using Method Post AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, postman

can someone fix it, when i using postman my restfull is good but not from my client side

```
   var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8098/getfiles',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        data: { 'selectedFiles': 'D:\\quadtech\\Intellegent\\AppSpringBoot\\input\\bismillah.txt' }
    }   
    return $http(req).then(function(response){console.log(response); return response;}, function(){});
```

error in my console is

```
POST http://localhost:8098/getfiles 500 ()
```

this is request from postman
[image]

Comment: Your server expects form-data. You're sending JSON. That would be obvious if you looked at the request you're sending, in the network panel of your browser dev tools. Send the data in the right format, using the right content-type.

Comment: 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' i got error 500 then when using this

Answer (score 0):

Send using formData instead of data:

```
    var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8098/getfiles',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            formData: {
              'selectedFiles': fs.createReadStream('D:\\quadtech\\Intellegent\\AppSpringBoot\\input\\bismillah.txt') }
            }   
        return $http(req).then(function(response){console.log(response); return response;}, function(){});
```

see the docs: https://github.com/request/request#forms